# How to access the UITableViewCell of a QuickDialog cell element?

Tags: ios, quickdialog

I am trying to access the properties of the UITableViewCell of a QuickDialog form.

More specifically, I am trying to access the accessoryView property of a QEntryElement (QDateTimeInlineElement), which is "hidden" in the property list of the object I create.

I am trying to access the cell using

```
    UITableViewCell *thisCell = [dateelement getCellForTableView:self.quickDialogTableView controller:self];
```

But for some reasons nothing is displayed. I am trying to insert a UIButton in it, like this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"=" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
```

and then 
    thisCell.accessoryView = button;

Am I accessing the property in a wrong way or maybe the button is not created at all? No errors are displayed, but the accessoryView is empty.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't just call [element getCellForTableView] because cells don't really exist until the tableview tries to display them. This is the presentation model that the UITableView uses to display data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog/issues/133) looks very close to what you are asking. Basically, you first have to provide your own `QuickDialogStyleProvider`, implementing the `cell:willAppearForElement:atIndexPath:` method the way escoz suggests there:

> Once you get the call in the provider method, you have full control of the cell. You can just check if the cell is of type `QEntryTableViewCell`, and if it is, cast to that type and change the color/font of the `textField` property. A nice side effect is that this will also change the color for all subclasses, like the radio button, date/time fields, etc..

So, in your case you'd do something like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.quickDialogTableView.styleProvider = self;
}

- (void)cell:(UITableViewCell *)cell willAppearForElement:(QElement *)element atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([cell isKindOfClass:[QDateTimeInlineElement class]])
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setTitle:@"=" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);

        cell.accessoryView = button;
    }
}
```

Sorry if it's not fully correct, I'm away from Xcode at the moment.

Comment: Great answer @Gregory Goltsov. In general that is what I would do as well.

Comment: And it IS fully correct indeed.
I added `<QuickDialogStyleProvider>` to header file and     `self.quickDialogTableView.styleProvider = self;`
in `viewDidLoad` method. Now I can customize my AccessoryView. By doing so, controllerAccessoryAction is not working anymore so I added [button addTarget:...] to the button itself. 
Any suggestion on how I could edit this question thread to improve it is welcome!

Comment: @maggix I've updated the question to reflect your comment.  It helped me out (I was putting the delegate wire up in the init method).

Comment: Does anyone have an example of the implementation of this solution. I don't understand how to implement it.